# Special prices not showing in product pages

Tags: magento2, price, special-price, magento-2.1.7

hope you can help me.

Using 2.1.7 CE.

Site is ready to go live except one frustrating issue I can’t work out.

I have just moved to production mode and turned caches on. Since then:

- Special prices no longer appear in the product pages
- In the category pages, products with a special price applied show “as low as” product price, rather than a strikethrough of the regular price. I have no tiers set up.

If I flush cache OR reindex:

- Special price doesn’t not appear in the product page as described above UNLESS I open/refresh the product page of a product that has a special price immediately after flushing cache/reindexing. In this case, ONLY this product will display the special price on the product page - others will not display the special price. However, it doesn't appear to be browser related as if I clear browser cache/use another browser or device, again only this product will correctly show the special price while all others do not, as described above.
- Although the product page does not show the special price, if I add it to the basket the special price is correctly applied.
- There is no effect on the “as low as” issue.

Have considered it a theme issue and tried it with the Luma theme but the same problem persists.

Many thanks,

J

Comment: have you solved this issue by now?

Comment: Have you fixed?